# Symfony2 custom json serialization

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization, doctrine

I am wondering how I can personify the default JSON serialization with JMS on entities.

I have an object A that have a OneToMany relation with an object B.
I expose the object B and attrA from A object.

But instead of having the basic JSON

```
{'attrA' : 'foo', 'Bs' : {{'attrB' : 'bar'}, {'attrB' : 'baz'}, ...} }
```

I want to have

```
{'attrA' : 'foo', 'Bs' : {'bar', 'baz', ...}}
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this, is to play with [serializer's annotations](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations)

I assume your value objects looks like this

```
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $attrA;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection<Bar>
     */
    private $bs;
}

class Bar
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $attrB;
}
```

### Import annotations

First, if you didn't already, you need to import the annotations at the top of your files

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
```

### Set up a custom  getter

By default, JMS serializer gets the property value through reflection. My thoughts go on creating a [custom accessor](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor) for the serialization.
*Note: I assume your `bs` property is an [`ArrayCollection`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php). If not, you can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map)*

```
// Foo.php

/**
 * @Serializer\Accessor(getter="getBarArray")
 */
private $bs;

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection<string>
 */
public function getBarArray()
{
    return $this->getBs()->map(function (Bar $bar) {
        return $bar->getAttrB();
    });
}
```

Setting up a custom `Accessor(getter)` will force the serializer to use the getter instead of the reflection. This way, you can tweak any property value to get it in the format you want.

### Result

Serialization of these value objects would result in

```
{'attrA' : 'foo', 'Bs' : ['bar', 'baz', ...]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was exactly what I was expecting for :)